# 'str' object has no attribute 'fit' in seaborn distribution plot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to plot a distribution plot using seaborn but im getting the error:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I used the code:

```
sns.distplot(df['avg_ridership'],fit ='norm')
```

What may be the reason for it? Sample data is given below:

```
    Month   avg_ridership   Mon Year
0   1960-01    648          01  1960
1   1960-02    646          02  1960
2   1960-03    639          03  1960
3   1960-04    654          04  1960
4   1960-05    630          05  1960
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the description of the sns method? You have to make sure about the properly paramus and attributes of the function "distplot", maybe you wrong about the names, so something like that

Comment: that reads more like a comment than an answer. once you have sufficient reputation on this site you will be allowed to comment everywhere.